# Kivy App won't run in Visual Studio Code (Shows a black screen)

Tags: python, kivy

I completed the pong tutorial from Kivy's website. I ran it yesterday and it was working fine. Today, I tried making a snakegame. However, just drawing a white canvas wasn't working. I checked and rechecked tutorials and they were saying everything I was doing was fine. I decided to repast the code for Pong game again and see why it wasn't drawing my canvas in my snakegame. I kept getting this black screen. I know the code is right and it was working yesterday and it works in visual studio 2019. I change the file names back to pong.py and pong.kv and even imported builder just incase that was the issue. However, that turned out to not be the issue and I am still stuck with the same black screen. Does anyone know what is wrong?

[image: Pong App Running]

[image: Debug Output]

pong.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_file('pong.kv')


class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        # bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        # went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size          

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right
    
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height
    
    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)
        
    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)
    
    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
        
    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y
        
    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width - self.width
        center_y: root.center_y
```

Comment: I run your codes using file names  pong.py and pong.kv and can see a screen with a ping pong ball bouncing back and forth.  Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I can run the same code in visual studio 2019 without errors but when i run it in VS code i get this error. It was working fine yesterday. I tried restarting the computer and was still giving me the same error.

Comment: I run it in VS Code without error.   Any change to VS Code today ?

Comment: The code 100% works. The problem is definitely with VS code but I haven’t done anything unless it was an accidental keyboard press. I am thinking of reinstalling vs code and seeing if that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! Problem was I changed NVIDIA "preferred graphics processor" from Auto-select to High Performance in the NVIDIA Control Panel. This for some reason missed graphics with Visual Studio Code.